# Validate the date column whether it is in MMDDYY format or not

Tags: excel, vba

In an Excel sheet, one column is with date and we need to validate all the values in that column and check whether they are in `MMDDYY` format or not. If not, we need to highlight that specific cell with a colour.

```vb
Sub effectivedate() 
Dim a As Integer 
 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")
   For a = 2 To .Range("e" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
      k = .Range("e" & a) 
      p = Len(k) 
      If Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(k) = 1 And p <> 6 Then 
           .Range("e" & a).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 
      End If
   Next 
 End With
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check all the cells in that column and if any one is not in MMDDYY format highlet the cell with any colour.

Comment: I tried but not getting any idea about it, please any body help with the code.

Comment: I tried this code but it only checking wither the value having 6digits  or not.                                                                                   
 Sub effectivedate()
Dim a As Integer
  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")
    For a = 2 To .Range("e" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     k = .Range("e" & a)
    p = Len(k)
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(k) = 1 And p <> 6 Then
            .Range("e" & a).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
Next
End With

End Sub

Comment: I want it to check the value to be in MMDDYY format. if not highlet the cell with any colour

Comment: Please, edit your question and place the code there. It is not too understandable in a comment...

Comment: I am new to VBA and unable to find this. Can any one help me with this

Comment: I unable to add thia code in question as it giving errors. please check my code in coments if possible

Comment: Sub effectivedate()
Dim a As Integer
  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")
    For a = 2 To .Range("e" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     k = .Range("e" & a)
    p = Len(k)
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(k) = 1 And p <> 6 Then
            .Range("e" & a).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
Next
End With

End Sub

Comment: I edited your question and place there the code. Can you also paste there a picture showing the data range in discussion? Is the necessary date formatted looking as `121721` for today date? Where from does it come? How is formatted the column in discussion?

Comment: What date `051102` should mean?  11 of May 2002?

Comment: 051102 means 05-11-2002 as it is in MMDDYY format

Comment: If the column is formatted as Date, you should remove `p` variable completely. Excel keeps Date like a `Long` number. 5 digits... So your way of checking is wrong.

Comment: Can you please help me with the code, it helps me a lot.

Comment: I will post a code, but it will only check if that number is a Date. There is no standard way of determining if the format is DDMMYY, or MMDDYY, for the case of day less or equal to 12...

Comment: Please, test the code I posted and send some feedback.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please, test the next code. It creates the appropriate date from existing `Date` or `String` and color the cells keeping text with a length different from 6:

```
Sub MakeDateMMDDYY()
Dim ws As Worksheet, a As Long, lastR As Long
Dim txtD As String, arr, arrFin, rngCol As Range, colLett As String
 
 colLett = "F" 'the column letter where to be returned the processing result
               'if the code returns what you need, you can replade F with E
 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")
 lastR = ws.Range("E" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 arr = ws.Range("E2:E" & lastR).value    'place the range in an array for faster iteration
 ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)  'redim the array to receive the processing result
 
   For a = 1 To UBound(arr)
     txtD = ws.Range("E" & a + 1).text   'place the cell text in a string variable
     If Len(txtD) = 6 Then
         'create a date from the string and place it in the final array:
         arrFin(a, 1) = DateSerial(CLng(Right(txtD, 2)) + 2000, CLng(left(txtD, 2)), CLng(Mid(txtD, 3, 2))): 'Stop
     Else
         arrFin(a, 1) = txtD              'place the string in the final array
         If rngCol Is Nothing Then
            Set rngCol = ws.Range(colLett & a + 1)                'first time create the range to be colored
         Else
            Set rngCol = Union(rngCol, ws.Range(colLett & a + 1)) 'then, use a Union for the next cells to be colored
         End If
      End If
   Next
   With ws.Range(colLett & 2).Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1)           'format the range and drop the final array result
        .NumberFormat = "MMDDYY"
        .value = arrFin
   End With
   If Not rngCol Is Nothing Then rngCol.Interior.ColorIndex = 6   'color the range keeping the cells to be colored
End Sub
```

Comment: @Suresh Salluri Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, doesn't it work as you need?

Comment: Thanks man its working, but is there any to write like in 6 digits of date first 2 for montha and should between 1-12, second two for days and should between 1-31, last two for year like that?

Comment: like using left value for month, mid value for day and right vale for year

Comment: @Suresh Salluri I cannot understand what you mean, sorry... Aren't the date, as you show in your picture, in this format? Where from do you receive the data range to be processed? How this initial data range is formatted?

Comment: @Suresh Salluri I am asking about the data source, which probably should be as text, to supply a function able to correctly transform it in Date, as you need. Then, you can format it however you want...

Comment: What about a for loop to check the "obvious dates for the format MMDDYY or DDMMYY then set the rest? As the source must be one or the other?

Comment: @Solar Mike If I can see the source of the data range, which certainly is consistent, the processing should be relatively easy. Otherwise, I could only assume that the format is the one he needs. If the input range (a string, probably) is inconsistent from the point of view in discussion) it is impossible to separate the two cases (for day <=12). You can only analize the strings not being guessed by Excel as `Date`, for the first two characters number bigger than 12, but this will not solve the whole range. I can add something like that to the code, but its purpose looked to show the wrong D.

Comment: instead of date can we take text and it should have six digits and first two for month and second two for day and last two for year.

Comment: @Solar Mike Ups, I tagged you by mistake. The comment should tag the OP... I will delete it and copy with the correct tag. Sorry...

Comment: @Suresh Salluri Are you informing me about that? Where from to take text? Are you able to answer my above clarification questions?

Comment: @FaneDuru sorted, cheers.

Comment: @FaneDuru I (Solar Mike) replied "**sorted**" as you deleted the original comment you sent to me in error and so i removed mine where I queried you about the comment. This is getting to be hard work... And, to think, I voted your answer...

Comment: @Solar Mike It looks I'm tired. I cannot keep the step with these comments... :) I will become a master of comments deletion...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. 1)The condition here is Eff Date values should have 6 digits. 2) first two digits btwn 1-12(left) should have month value, next two digits btwn 1-31(mid) should have date value and last two digits btwn(yy) 00-99.   "MMDDYY"  if this condition not meet than that cell should be highlet in any colour

Comment: Any one please help me with code

Comment: @Suresh Salluri I will be able to help only If I will be able to understand what you have and what you want... So, is the range to be processed **formatted as Date**? In order to check that, what does formula`=Year(E2)` return? The real year, a wrong one, or an error? If a correct number, please fill down the formula and see if any error, or wrong number appears. When such a case, what text does the referenced cell when you see such an error, show? if not confidential, can you share the workbook you use? Or a dummy one having only a similar column... Besides that, is there text of less digits?

Comment: @Suresh Salluri Please, test the updated code and send some feedback. I made some assumptions and it my be working as you need. If not, can you share a dummy workbook keeping such a column?